# skimage resize giving weird output

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I'm resizing an image using `skimage.transform.resize` but I'm getting a really weird output and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.transform
plt.imshow(y)
h,w,c = y.shape
x = skimage.transform.resize(y, (256, (w*256)/h), preserve_range=True)
plt.imshow(x)
```

Here is my input image y (240, 320, 3):

[image]

Here is my output image x (256, 341, 3):

[image]

**Edit:**
Okay it seems to work fine if I change `preserve_range=False`. But why won't it allow me to keep the current range?

**Edit:**
I'm randomly sampling frames from videos using OpenCV. Here's the function that returns a frame from the video path I pass to it.

```
def read_random_frames(vid_file):

   vid = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_file)
   # get the number of frames    
   num_frames = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
   # randomly select frame
   p_frame = random.randint(0, (num_frames-1))
   # get frame
   vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, p_frame)
   ret, frame = vid.read()
   # convert from BGR to RGB
   frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

   return frame
```

I have a list of video paths and I use a `map` function to retrieve the frames then I convert the outputed list to a numpy array:

```
 batch_frames = map(lambda vid: read_random_frames(vid), train_vids_batch)
 frame_tensor = np.asarray(batch_frames)
 y = frame_tensor[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is simply because by preserving the range I end up with a float in the range [0, 255] whereas `pyplot.imshow` is only capable of displaying MxNx3 float arrays in the range [0.0, 1.0]. When I convert the output to an uint8 using `z = np.copy(x).astype('uint8')` it displays fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. As **@RHankins** mentioned, `plt.imshow` can display either float images with pixels within range `[0.0, 1.0]` or integer images with pixels within range [0, 255].
2. `skimage.transform.resize` calls a function `wrap` ([_warps.py#L161](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/_warps.py#L161)) which always converts an input image to `float64` ([_warps.py#L797](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/_warps.py#L797)).

That's why you always need to convert the output to whatever you prefer. For example to 
resize image and get `np.uint8` output image within range in `[0, 255]` you do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
import skimage.transform
x = img_as_ubyte(skimage.transform.resize(y, (100, 100)))
plt.imshow(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a full example? How do you read your image data, what is the original format? (Using `y = scipy.misc.imread("somefile.png")` on a .png-file it works perfectly on my machine)

What is the data-type (and `ndarray.dtype`) of your data?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.transform
from scipy.misc import imread

y = imread("tree.png")

plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(y)
h,w,c = y.shape
x = skimage.transform.resize(y, (256, (w*256)//h), preserve_range=True)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to convert the floating point image to unsigned integer in-order to display the image. Below is a simple resize example.

```
def ski_resize(path):
     image = imread(path)[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
     img = resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
     # The below line will convert float to uint8
     img = img.astype(np.uint8)
     return img, image
```