# Skimage - Weird results of resize function

Tags: python, image, image-resizing, scikit-image

I am trying to resize a `.jpg` image with `skimage.transform.resize function`. Function returns me weird result (see image below). I am not sure if it is a bug or just wrong use of the function.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, color
from skimage.transform import resize

rgb = io.imread("../../small_dataset/" + file)
# show original image
img = Image.fromarray(rgb, 'RGB')
img.show()

rgb = resize(rgb, (256, 256))
# show resized image
img = Image.fromarray(rgb, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

Original image:

[image: original]

Resized image:

[image: resized]

I allready checked [skimage resize giving weird output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227492/skimage-resize-giving-weird-output), but I think that my bug has different propeties.

Update: Also rgb2lab function has similar bug.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that **skimage** is converting the pixel data type of your array after resizing the image. The original image has a 8 bits per pixel, of type `numpy.uint8`, and the resized pixels are `numpy.float64` variables.

The resize operation is correct, but the result is not being correctly displayed. For solving this issue, I propose 2 different approaches:

1. To **change the data structure** of the resulting image. Prior to changing to uint8 values, the pixels have to be converted to a 0-255 scale, as they are on a 0-1 normalized scale:

   ```
    # ...
    # Do the OP operations ...
    resized_image = resize(rgb, (256, 256))
    # Convert the image to a 0-255 scale.
    rescaled_image = 255 * resized_image
    # Convert to integer data type pixels.
    final_image = rescaled_image.astype(np.uint8)
    # show resized image
    img = Image.fromarray(final_image, 'RGB')
    img.show()
   ```

#### Update: This method is deprecated, as per [`scipy.misc.imshow`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imshow.html)

2. To **use another library** for displaying the image. Taking a look at the [Image library documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes), there isn't any mode supporting 3xfloat64 pixel images. However, the [scipy.misc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html) library has the appropriate tools for converting the array format in order to display it correctly:

```py
from scipy import misc
# ...
# Do OP operations
misc.imshow(resized_image)
```

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. Using of `matplotlib` is also ok.

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.img_as_ubyte