# Image resizing problem with Python using Cat and Dog data

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I'm a newbei at Data Visualization, Machine Learning and Deep Learning topics. I'm trying to improve myself, but I stucked a topic when I try to implement a visualization.

In details, I tried to implement a kernel on 'Kaggle', my data is Cat and Dog images. I have train and test datas. The problem is that my train data has too many pictures that are different size, pixels and shapes. I want to make all of them in a 1 shape type.(For example, I want to make all of the pictures as 64x64 pixels, or 128x128 etc.)

```
""" I tried different codes to adjust its shapes and create plot:
I tried to reach 2 goals:
1. Convert the dog and cat images from RGB to Grayscale
2. Make all of the images 128x128, or 64x64 """


# One of the codes I've tried
img_size = 128
basewidth = 128
for image in tqdm(os.listdir(train_cat)): 
    path = os.path.join(train_cat, image)
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    try:
       wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
       hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
       img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    except:
        pass
    np_img=np.asarray(img)

for image2 in tqdm(os.listdir(train_dog)): 
    path = os.path.join(train_dog, image2)
    img2 = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    try:
        wpercent = (basewidth / float(img2.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img2.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
        img2 = img2.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

    except:
        pass
    np_img2=np.asarray(img2) 

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(np_img.reshape(img_size, img_size))
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(np_img2.reshape(img_size, img_size))
plt.axis('off')


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Another way:

image_size = 128
for image in tqdm(os.listdir(train_dog)): 
    path = os.path.join(train_dog, image)
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    img = cv2.resize(img, (image_size, image_size)).flatten()   
    np_img=np.asarray(img)

for image2 in tqdm(os.listdir(train_cat)): 
    path = os.path.join(train_cat, image2)
    img2 = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (image_size, image_size)).flatten() 
    np_img2=np.asarray(img2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(np_img.reshape(image_size, image_size))
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(np_img2.reshape(image_size, image_size))
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Cat and Dogs in GrayScale")
```

## Output for first one

```
ValueError         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-0984b7467972> in <module>
     28 plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
     29 plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
---> 30 plt.imshow(np_img.reshape(img_size, img_size))
     31 plt.axis('off')
     32 plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)


ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 76964 into shape (300,300)
```

## Output for second one

```
error    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-99d190c6fd41> in <module>
      4     path = os.path.join(train_dog, image)
      5     img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
----> 6     img = cv2.resize(img, (image_size, image_size)).flatten()
      7     np_img=np.asarray(img)
      8 

error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3718:     error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

**As I mentioned above, I tried to make a convertion from RGB to Grayscale, and make the images' size 1 type(128x128 optionally). I believed there is no mistake to convertion but resize is a problem that I can't solve for 2-3 days, eventhough I made tons of researches. I'm not sure but it could be a simple problem, like a said, I'm a beginner for now.**

Note: I added 2 way of codes because there are the codes I understood best. I hope, you can help me, or teach me a new way, thank you in advance :)

```
#Appendixes:
```

[Cat and Dog Dataset:](https://www.kaggle.com/tongpython/cat-and-dog)
https://www.kaggle.com/tongpython/cat-and-dog

[The resizes and grayscale codes I've tried to implement are taken from: 
 (In[5])](https://www.kaggle.com/gulsahdemiryurek/image-classification-with-logistic-regression)

[Base kaggle I'm saw in order to data that has images (In[2](https://www.kaggle.com/gulsahdemiryurek/image-classification-with-logistic-regression))](https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/deep-learning-tutorial-for-beginners)

Comment: Welcome to SO; this is a standard image processing question, and it has nothing to do with `deep-learning`, `classification`, or `logistic-regression` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `opencv` and `python-imaging-library`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid mixing OpenCV and PIL when performing image processing. One reason is because OpenCV uses `BGR` format while PIL uses `RGB` format. Choose one library and stick with it. To convert an image to grayscale with OpenCV, you can use [`cv2.cvtColor()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) with the `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` or `cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY` flag

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

or just pass in a flag when reading in the image

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png', 0) # OR
# image = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

---

To resize, you can simply use [`cv2.resize()`](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)

```
resized = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64)) # OR
# resized = cv2.resize(image, (128, 128))
```

Note, `cv2.resize()` does not maintain aspect ratio. If you want to maintain aspect ratio, look at [`imutils.resize()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/convenience.py#L65). You may not get the exact shape dimensions though

```
resized = imutils.resize(image, width=64) # OR
# resized = imutils.resize(image, width=128)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **`skimage`** for image resizing and gray/rgb conversion as well.

### Image Resizing

[`skimage.transform.resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) Docs

```py
from skimage.transform import resize
# resize your grayscale image to 128x128
resized_image = resize(gray_image, (128,128))
```

### Grayscale Conversion

[`skimage.color.rgb2gray`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2gray) Docs

```py
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
gray_image = rgb2gray(color_image)
```

## Additional Information

1. [Skimage - Weird results of resize function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257947/skimage-weird-results-of-resize-function)
2. [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)